# Hall and Wellner survival function simultaneous confidence band

Tags: confidence-interval, survival, censoring, kaplan-meier

I was trying to implement the Hall and Wellner simultaneous confidence band decribed in:

Applied Survival Analysis, Second Edition (ISBN-13: 978-0471754992), p. 33.

But the table (Appedix 3) requires the parameter:
$$
\hat a=\frac{n\hatσ^2(t_{(m)})}{1+n\hat σ^2(t_{(m)})}
$$
Which in turn requires the variance of the log of the Kaplan-Meier estimator for the largest non-censored value of time:
$$
\hat σ^2(t_{(m)})=\sum_{t_{(i)}\leq t_{(m)}} \frac{d_i}{n_i(n_i-d_i)}
$$

In my case said value is non-censored, thus:
$$
d_i=n_i
$$
Generating a division by 0.
I suspect the correct value for $\hat a$ in this case is 1 but I'm not sure.